# What is the best practice way to write the parameter for a redirect_to method which redirects to a show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on Rails, seems to be multiple ways to write the parameter given to the redirect_to method for redirecting to the show page of the object, wondering which way write code is the best practice way.

```
redirect_to message_path(@message)

redirect_to message_path

redirect_to @message
```

I see people differentiating their syntax as in when writing in the controller action, people seem to use `redirect_to @message` more often and when they are in the view, they tend to use `redirect_to message_path(@message)`

Answer (score 1):

I think its about personal preference or style guide used by your company. At my workplace we tend to stick with `redirect_to @message` for show action.

Also your second example won't work `redirect_to message_path`, you need to change it to `redirect_to message_path(@message)` or `redirect_to message_path(@message.id)`.

Also be aware that in Rails you can also use `redirect_to message_url(@message)` for absolute path.

Comment: hmm interesting. I would like to hear what others think about their preference or any standards.

Comment: How does Rails know that `redirect_to @message` goes to the show action?

Comment: @the12 @Rober I haven't check source code but I am guessing once you  pass @message object to `redirect_to` method then rails will call `url_for` on @message object to get the url. e.g `url_for @message`. you can test this in rails console.`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers; @message = Message.first; url_for @message`. It will return output something like this `http://localhost:3000/messages/1`